# Internal error from Google Pub/Sub when trying to update

Tags: go, google-cloud-pubsub, exponential-backoff

I keep getting the following error when trying to update a Pub/Sub subscription's retry policy:

`rpc error: code = Internal desc = A service error has occurred. Please retry your request. If the error persists, please report it. [code=e8c0]`

Given the subscription already exists, without any retry policy, and using `go 1.19` and `cloud.google.com/go/pubsub v1.28.0`, this is the code that reproduces it:

```golang
sub, err := client.GetSubscription(
    context.Background(), 
    &pubsubpb.GetSubscriptionRequest{
        Subscription: subscriptionName,
        })
// error check omitted for clarity
sub.RetryPolicy = &pubsubpb.RetryPolicy{
    MinimumBackoff: durationpb.New(c.config.MinimumBackoff),
    MaximumBackoff: durationpb.New(c.config.MaximumBackoff),
}
req := pubsubpb.UpdateSubscriptionRequest{
    Subscription: sub,
    UpdateMask: &fieldmaskpb.FieldMask{
        Paths: []string{"retry_policy.minimum_backoff", "retry_policy.maximum_backoff"},
    },
}
_, err := client.UpdateSubscription(context.Background(), &req)
// err is "A service error has occurred. Please retry your request. If the error persists, please report it. [code=e8c0]"
```

Otherwise, the subscription is completely usable, so it doesn't look like there is any problem with the subscription itself. Am I doing anything the wrong way?

Answer (score 1):

For internal errors, it is best to open a [support case](https://console.cloud.google.com/support) so that it can be investigated. It requires looking into backend information about your subscription.